# Website shortcut with Powershell

Tags: powershell, shortcut

**Hi everybody,**

My goal is that i can run a Powershell script which then creates a shortcut of the Website which is opened at the moment. I know it's no problem to create a shortcut from a path or document, but now i habe to do it from a website. 
First of all, is that even possible? If yes, do i need a add on or does it just work with Powershell?

I haven't found anything usefull in the internet. I'm not really skilled with Powershell so that's why i'm not sure if that is even possible.

I'm thankful at any hint.

Greetings.

Comment: What browser are you using ? It seems doable with IE. Otherwise, you could try to check the history files on disk for the last entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yehellow

I don't know how to do it in powershell, but there is another programming language called AutoIt. It's made for automations exactly like this. Just download it from the [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/) page.

Here is the code that worked for me. If you need to inport it into your powershell script just compile the AutoIt code into an .exe, run it with powershell and read the output from a .txt file.

> Syntax:

```
#include <IE.au3>
$oIE = _IEAttach("*TITLE OF THE PAGE*")
$url = _IEPropertyGet($oIE, "locationurl")
```

> Example:

```
#include <IE.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
$oIE = _IEAttach("Google")
$url = _IEPropertyGet($oIE, "locationurl")
MsgBox(0,$url,$url)
```

As far as i know it only works for IE. Sorry for not having a solutoin for Powershell.

Comment: Thanks, i will try it.

Comment: Sorry wasn't able to try it. I will try it tonight and write you then tomorrow morning. The problem is i have to do it for my Company where i don't have the rights to install. That's why i habe to wait until i'm home. But thanks for asking.

Comment: Ohh, I know that problem. I use a virtual machiene for testing new programs. Also you can write the script on the virtual machine, compile it as .exe and use it on your normal machiene. There's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: So you mean if i write the script on a Computer with admin rights. I can run it then on a non admin Computer? Even if there is no autoit on the Computer? 
As you can see i'm new with scripting so sorry if it was a "stupid" question.

Comment: Yes, thats right as long you dont script something what requires admin rights.

Comment: Sorry forgot to answer. With autoit it should work. My problem is now i have to do it with powershell. The reason is that autoit is to "easy". But still thanks for your help!

Comment: you could still use the exe form of your skript and use it with powershell ;) good luck